# ubuntu16.04 python3 pip install sasl

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, sasl

error information:
[image]
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Reason：The saslwrapper.h dependency library is not installed
Please refer to the solution:http://superset.apache.org/installation.html